# О значениях слова "болеть"

Tags: этимология

Как получилось, что слово "болеть" стало употребляться и в значении "быть на чьей-то стороне", "желать кому-то победы". При чем тут болезнь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считалось, что они ведут себя как больные, т.е. одержимые.
Отсюда же итальянское тиффози, хотя не совсем понятно, является ли русское калькой или возникло независимо.

Добавлено.
Кстати говоря, "болеть" в значении "переживать (за кого, что)" появилось в русском языке задолго до болельщиков. Но оно было связано с "болеть душой" и даже при сходстве значений вряд ли могло оказать какое-то влияние на появление "фанатского" смысла.